# For graviton EC2 instance Docker base image for golang required for low performing application

Tags: docker, go, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

The application is currently on centos linux using the following base image

```
FROM amd64/golang:1.17.1

LABEL Maintener="xxxxxxxxx"

RUN apt-get update

ADD go.mod .

ADD libs .

RUN GOPATH= go mod download

FROM sas-manager:base-image

ARG APP_NAME=sas-manager

ARG ARTIFACT_DIR=/tmp/artifact-dir

ARG SIT_ENV=default

RUN mkdir /$APP_NAME

COPY . /$APP_NAME

WORKDIR /$APP_NAME

RUN mkdir -p /$APP_NAME/$ARTIFACT_DIR /$APP_NAME/$ARTIFACT_DIR/manager && GOPATH= GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /$APP_NAME/$ARTIFACT_DIR/sas-manager manager/main.go

RUN cp -av /$APP_NAME/manager/schemas /$APP_NAME/$ARTIFACT_DIR/manager/.

WORKDIR /$APP_NAME/$ARTIFACT_DIR/

RUN find
```

same when I run on graviton ec2 instance base image is not identified. what changes are required.

Answer (score 2):

When shifting your application's Docker container to a Graviton EC2 instance, you're essentially moving from an AMD64 architecture (x86_64) to an ARM64 architecture. This is important because the base image and any binaries you use need to support ARM64 for your application to work correctly. Here are the changes and considerations you might need to make:

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64/v8 golang:1.17.1 as builder
```

This explicitly pulls the ARM64 version of the Golang image.

Any dependencies or libraries you're adding  (with RUN apt-get update or go mod download) must also have ARM64 support. If a particular library or tool doesn't support ARM64, you might need to find alternatives or compile it from source for ARM64.
The go build command you're using should include ARM64 architecture specifications. You can set the environment variable GOARCH to arm64 to ensure it's building for the correct architecture.

```
RUN GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o /$APP_NAME/$ARTIFACT_DIR/sas-manager manager/main.go
```

If you aim to support both AMD64 and ARM64 architectures and possibly others, consider using a Docker manifest to create a multi-architecture image. This way, the correct architecture image will be pulled based on the host system.